# How to set a value in a list based on the current filtered column value

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, filter, designer-workflow, document-set

I have edited my document set Welcome Page to include a web part of a "Notes" list. This list is filtered so that only notes pertaining to the currently viewed document set are visible.

Question: when the user clicks "Add new item" in the filtered Notes web part while on the Welcome Page how can I automatically populate the ID in the new note with the filter value? Essentially, if the Welcome Page is docsethomepage.aspx?ID=2 and currently showing all notes from my Notes list where NotesID =  DocSetID (in this example "2"), how can SharePoint Designer 2010 "know" that this value is "2"? If I know how to lookup this value I can then use the "Set field in current item" action to set the NotesID to "2".

Answer (score 1):

Your Notes web part already knows what the ID value is as it has a number of items with that value in already. I would probably use some jQuery to replace the Add New Item link with your own link passing through the ID as a parameter and then customising the new Notes form to use that parameter to automatically populate the field.